# why should I make a copy of a data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, copy, chained-assignment

When selecting a sub dataframe from a parent dataframe, I noticed that some programmers make a copy of the data frame using the `.copy()` method. For example,

```py
X = my_dataframe[features_list].copy()
```

...instead of just

```py
X = my_dataframe[features_list]
```

Why are they making a copy of the data frame? What will happen if I don't make a copy?

Comment: My guess is they are taking extra precaution to not modify the source data frame. Probably unnecessary, but when you're throwing something together interactively, better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 371, accepted):

This answer has been deprecated in newer versions of pandas. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#evaluation-order-matters)

---

This expands on Paul's answer. In Pandas, indexing a DataFrame returns a reference to the initial DataFrame. Thus, changing the subset will change the initial DataFrame. Thus, you'd want to use the copy if you want to make sure the initial DataFrame shouldn't change. Consider the following code:

```
df = DataFrame({'x': [1,2]})
df_sub = df[0:1]
df_sub.x = -1
print(df)
```

You'll get:

```
   x
0 -1
1  2
```

In contrast, the following leaves df unchanged:

```
df_sub_copy = df[0:1].copy()
df_sub_copy.x = -1
```

Comment: is this a deep copy?

Comment: Yes. The default mode is "deep" copy! https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Comment: I found this article on the issue of deep/shallow copies in panda/numpy to be quite clear and comprehensive: https://realpython.com/pandas-settingwithcopywarning/

Comment: If I change any cell within a `function` then also such manipulation will reflect on the original `dataframe`?

Comment: This do not hold true anymore, right?

Answer (score 90):

Because if you don't make a copy then the indices can still be manipulated elsewhere even if you assign the dataFrame to a different name.

For example:

```
df2 = df
func1(df2)
func2(df)
```

func1 can modify df by modifying df2, so to avoid that:

```
df2 = df.copy()
func1(df2)
func2(df)
```

Comment: Wait wait wait, can you explain WHY this occurs?  Doesn't make sense.

Comment: it is because in the first example, ` df2 = df`, both variables reference the same DataFrame instance. So any changes made to `df` or `df2` will be made to the same object instance. Whereas in the `df2 = df.copy()` a second object instance is created, a copy of the first one, but now `df` and `df2` reference to different object instances and any changes will be made to their respective DataFrame instance.

Comment: A simple example is like below:

Answer (score 29):

It's necessary to mention that returning copy or view depends on kind of indexing.

The pandas documentation says:

> Returning a view versus a copy
>
> The rules about when a view on the data is returned are entirely
>   dependent on NumPy. Whenever an array of labels or a boolean vector
>   are involved in the indexing operation, the result will be a copy.
>   With single label / scalar indexing and slicing, e.g. df.ix[3:6] or
>   df.ix[:, 'A'], a view will be returned.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.12/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy and newer version https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Answer (score 26):

The primary purpose is to avoid chained indexing and eliminate the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

Here chained indexing is something like `dfc['A'][0] = 111`

The document said chained indexing should be avoided in [Returning a view versus a copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy). Here is a slightly modified example from that document:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: dfc = pd.DataFrame({'A':['aaa','bbb','ccc'],'B':[1,2,3]})

In [3]: dfc
Out[3]:
    A   B
0   aaa 1
1   bbb 2
2   ccc 3

In [4]: aColumn = dfc['A']

In [5]: aColumn[0] = 111
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

In [6]: dfc
Out[6]:
    A   B
0   111 1
1   bbb 2
2   ccc 3
```

Here the `aColumn` is a view and not a copy from the original DataFrame, so modifying `aColumn` will cause the original `dfc` be modified too. Next, if we index the row first:

```
In [7]: zero_row = dfc.loc[0]

In [8]: zero_row['A'] = 222
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

In [9]: dfc
Out[9]:
    A   B
0   111 1
1   bbb 2
2   ccc 3
```

This time `zero_row` is a copy, so the original `dfc` is not modified.

From these two examples above, we see it's ambiguous whether or not you want to change the original DataFrame. This is especially dangerous if you write something like the following:

```
In [10]: dfc.loc[0]['A'] = 333
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

In [11]: dfc
Out[11]:
    A   B
0   111 1
1   bbb 2
2   ccc 3
```

This time it didn't work at all. Here we wanted to change `dfc`, but we actually modified an intermediate value `dfc.loc[0]` that is a copy and is discarded immediately. It’s very hard to predict whether the intermediate value like `dfc.loc[0]` or `dfc['A']` is a view or a copy, so it's not guaranteed whether or not original DataFrame will be updated. That's why chained indexing should be avoided, and pandas generates the `SettingWithCopyWarning` for this kind of chained indexing update.

Now is the use of `.copy()`. To eliminate the warning, make a copy to express your intention explicitly:

```
In [12]: zero_row_copy = dfc.loc[0].copy()

In [13]: zero_row_copy['A'] = 444 # This time no warning
```

Since you are modifying a copy, you know the original `dfc` will never change and you are not expecting it to change. Your expectation matches the behavior, then the `SettingWithCopyWarning` disappears.

Note, If you do want to modify the original DataFrame, the document suggests you use `loc`:

```
In [14]: dfc.loc[0,'A'] = 555

In [15]: dfc
Out[15]:
    A   B
0   555 1
1   bbb 2
2   ccc 3
```

Comment: Nice answer. I did not notice before that pandas gives that warning about about "trying to be set on a copy of a slice" even when the object is a view, not  a copy.  First example with `aColumn` surprised me.

Comment: And doesn't this mean the pandas warning is the opposite of the problem or at minimum highly confusing? It says to me, wait, you're trying to change a copy, don't do that. It should say, wait, you need to first make a copy() [new pointer] or something might go wrong later. And my response would be, yeah but I know what I'm doing so be quiet, I don't want to make a copy all the time first

Answer (score 17):

Assumed you have data frame as below

```
df1
     A    B    C    D
4 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
5 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
6 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
6 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
```

When you would like create another `df2` which is identical to `df1`, without `copy`

```
df2=df1
df2
     A    B    C    D
4 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
5 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
6 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
6 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
```

And would like modify the df2 value only as below

```
df2.iloc[0,0]='changed'

df2
         A    B    C    D
4  changed -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
5       -1 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
6       -1 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
6       -1 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
```

At the same time the df1 is changed as well

```
df1
         A    B    C    D
4  changed -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
5       -1 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
6       -1 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
6       -1 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
```

Since two df as same `object`, we can check it by using the `id`

```
id(df1)
140367679979600
id(df2)
140367679979600
```

So they as same object and one change another one will pass the same value as well.

---

If we add the `copy`, and now `df1` and `df2` are considered as different `object`, if we do the same change to one of them the other will not change.

```
df2=df1.copy()
id(df1)
140367679979600
id(df2)
140367674641232

df1.iloc[0,0]='changedback'
df2
         A    B    C    D
4  changed -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
5       -1 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
6       -1 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
6       -1 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0
```

---

Good to mention, when you subset the original dataframe, it is safe to add the copy as well in order to avoid the `SettingWithCopyWarning`

Comment: going through your answer and @cgold 's answer, I see that in his answer the **id** of `df_sub` is different than `df` as can be understood as logical. Does the object created by `df_sub` have a **pointer** or something to `df`?

Answer (score 2):

In general it is safer to work on copies than on original data frames, except when you know that you won't be needing the original anymore and want to proceed with the manipulated version. Normally, you would still have some use for the original data frame to compare with the manipulated version, etc. Therefore, most people work on copies and merge at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas Deep copy leaves the initial DataFrame unchanged.

This feature is particularly useful when you want to normalize a DataFrame and want to keep the initial df unchanged.
For instance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(2,10))
```

then you normalize the data:

```
# Using Sklearn MinMaxSacaler method
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
```

and you make a new df based on the first one and want the first one unchanged,
you have to use .copy() method

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df).copy() # Deep Copy
for i in range(10):
    pd_features[i] = scaler.fit_transform(unnormal_pd_features[i].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

or else your original df will change too.

Comment: You raise a good point but this would have been better with something reproducible

Answer (score 1):

I was so careless using copy() until I use that line of code below
without using copy(), the changes in df_genel3 effects df_genel

```
df_genel3 = df_genel
df_genel3.loc[(df_genel3['Hareket']=='İmha') , 'Hareket_Tutar'] = tutar
```

copy() solved the problem

```
df_genel3 = df_genel.copy()
df_genel3.loc[(df_genel3['Hareket']=='İmha') , 'Hareket_Tutar'] = tutar
```