# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I keep getting the warning in the subject in the following situations:

Step 1:

```
df.rename(columns={'one':'one_a'}, inplace=True)
```

Step 2:

```
df.drop(['one', 'two', 'three'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

How do I fix?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Easiest fix (and probably good programming practice) would be to not do inplace operations, e.g.

```
df2 = df.rename(columns={'one':'one_a'})
```

Comment: What if I did this? df = df.rename(columns={'one':'one_a'})

Comment: And if I keep it as I had it, is it okay to ignore the warning in these cases?

Comment: It is OK to ignore it, but I would recommend you assign a list of new column names to `df.columns`. Basically, `df.columns = ['list', 'of', 'new', 'names']`. And for `df.drop`, it would be better to write `df = df.loc[:,['columns', 'to', 'keep']].copy()`

Comment: @VinceBowdren well it's a matter of taste i suppose but inplace operations don't gel well with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming

Comment: How is it good programming practice to hold multiple copies of a dataset for renaming purposes only ? Would the size of the dataset affect your answer ?

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem and to fix I did the following:

```
new_df = df.copy()
new_df.rename(columns={'one':'one_a'}, inplace=True)
new_df.drop(['one', 'two', 'three'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Or you can do

```
df.is_copy = False
```

You were probably using a copy of your original DF (ex: you were manipulating your DF before that) and that's why you were receiving the warning. More on copy:

[why should I make a copy of a data frame in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673231/why-should-i-make-a-copy-of-a-data-frame-in-pandas)

Comment: This might be my new strategy going forward to avoid these warnings -- copious amounts of `.copy()` tagged on to the ends of my operations

Answer (score 6):

One way around it is to remove *inplace=True*, then use:

```
df = df.drop(['one', 'two', 'three'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are work with jupyter notebook you can restart and runall . when i got this error then restart and run and it works fine with same code.

```
movies.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the warning mentioned...