# Trying to create a new column delivers A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem. I want to create a new column `adress`. Before that I want to get only all columns where `namecode` === `code` but unfortunately I got an error `A value is trying to be set on a copy ...`. I looked at (see below) but nothing worked for me.

- [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)
- [Pandas DataFrame: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728421/pandas-dataframe-settingwithcopywarning-a-value-is-trying-to-be-set-on-a-copy)
- [SettingWithCopyWarning even when using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573452/settingwithcopywarning-even-when-using-locrow-indexer-col-indexer-value)
- [Python Pandas Warning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961448/python-pandas-warning-a-value-is-trying-to-be-set-on-a-copy-of-a-slice-from-a-d)

```py
    customerId  code    namecode    name    street          adresscode
0   1           1       1           Mike    Long Street     458
1   2           1       1           Jucie   Short Street    856
2   3           9999    48           Max    Average Street  874
```

```py
import pandas as pd

import pandas as pd
d = {'customerId': [1, 2, 3],
     'code': [1, 1, 9999],
     'name_code': [1, 1, 48],
     'name': ['Mike', 'Jucie', 'Max'],
     'street': ['Long Street', 'Short Street', 'Average Street'],
     'adresscode': ['458', '856', '874']
    }
df_old = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

display(df_old)

df_new = df_old.loc[df_old['code'] == df_old['name_code']]


>>> df_new['adress'] = df_new ['name'].copy() + df_new ['street'].copy() + df_new ['adresscode'].copy()

[OUT]
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead


>>> df_new['adress'] = df_new .loc['name','street','adresscode']

[OUT]
IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

What I want

```py
    customerId  code    namecode    name    street          adresscode adress
0   1           1       1           Mike    Long Street     458        Mike Long Street 458
1   2           1       1           Jucie   Short Street    856        Jucie Short Street 856
```

Comment: your code is currently not reproducible

Comment: I still get different errors, for instance `df_new.loc['name','street','adresscode']` makes no sense in pandas, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please try `df_new['adress'] = df_new ['name'].copy() + df_new ['street'].copy() + df_new ['adresscode'].copy()`. I want to create a new column `adress`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy when slicing, not when assigning:

```
df_new = df_old.loc[df_old['code'] == df_old['name_code']].copy()
df_new['adress'] = df_new['name'] + df_new['street'] + df_new['adresscode']
```

output (without `SettingWithCopyWarning`):

```
   customerId  code  name_code   name        street adresscode  \
0           1     1          1   Mike   Long Street        458   
1           2     1          1  Jucie  Short Street        856   

                 adress  
0    MikeLong Street458  
1  JucieShort Street856
```

For you other slicing, you need to use a list of columns:

```
df_new = df_old[['name','street','adresscode']].copy()
# OR
df_new = df_old.loc[:, ['name','street','adresscode']].copy()
```