# Python lambda function with 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, dataframe, apply

This is a fragment of my code in Python. This code perfectly changes dataframe X_real_zeros, but it also changes X, why it happens?

```
X_real_zeros = X
for column in numeric_cols:
     X_real_zeros[column] = X[column].apply(lambda x: 0 if np.isnan(x) == 1 else x)
```

If I apply something like this:

```
X['columnii'] = X[column].apply(lambda x: 0 if np.isnan(x) == 1 else x)
```

It won't change the X[column] in initial dataframe X.

Comment: Thanks to all! It really works.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line `X_real_zeros = X`, instead of just assign you should use:

```
X_real_zeros = X.copy()
```

You may refer to [why should I make a copy of a data frame in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673231/why-should-i-make-a-copy-of-a-data-frame-in-pandas) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `X_real_zeros = X` you don't create a copy of X called X_real_zeros, you create a new binding with your dataframe called X_real_zeros, that is X and X_real_zeros point to the same space in memory. It works the same as with lists or dict, the solution is to use an explicit copy.

```
X_real_zeros = X.copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign

```
X_real_zeros = X
```

X_real_zeros is being assigned an internal reference to object X. So as X_real_zeros gets mutated, X also changes values. To safely copy variables, do:

```
X.copy()
```

This will create a new copy of X and you will be able to safely change X_real_zeros.