# Why does formatting of a dataframe automatically get applied to another?

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if this is a really dumb question. I'm a total noob at pandas and can't even figure out what key words to use to search for a solution for the problem I have.

Basically, I have a numeric data frame,

```
numeric_df = pd.DataFrame({"colA": [1.23, 2.34, 3.45],
                    "colB":[1.00, 2.00, 3.00]})
```

Now I create a second df that duplicates the value of numeric_df

```
formatted_df = numeric_df
```

Then I format the two columns in "formatted_df" according  my needs, I'm doing it this way because I want to keep the values in numeric_df as numbers, so I can operate on them later.

```
formatted_df["colA"] = formatted_df["colA"].map("${:}".format)
formatted_df["colB"] = formatted_df["colB"].map("{:}Years".format)
```

But now, if I view numeric_df, its columns are already formatted and converged into a string. What is causing the problem? Why does my map method modify the original data frame?

Thank you in advance for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `formatted_df = numeric_df` mean the variables share the same memory footprint. Referencing the same object. To manipulate one independently you need a seperate object. For this you can `clone` an object or Pandas offers `copy()`

```
formatted_df = numeric_df.copy()
```

[why should I make a copy of a data frame in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673231/why-should-i-make-a-copy-of-a-data-frame-in-pandas)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes perfect sense.