# assigning pandas df slice via iloc is by reference?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a new user of python and pandas, and I don't understand how assigning a slice of a pandas df1 to another df2 via the iloc "slicer", copies the data from df1 via reference.

The example code below illustrates my problem. If I use the assignment `y = 123`, then x stays unchanged. However, if I modify `y.iloc[:,:]` then by "magic" also x changes. Is `y.iloc` a pointer to x? if `y.iloc` is a pointer to x, then why does x stay unchanged if I modify y directly via assignment `y = 123`?

```
d = {'col1': [5]}
x = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print('x equals')
print(x)
y = x.iloc[:,:]
print('y equals')
print(y)

#why does the y.iloc[:,:]=123 also modify x?
y.iloc[0,0] = 123 
#y = 123 #this way x is unchanged.

print('y equals')
print(y)
print('x equals')
print(x)
```

Comment: After some googling, my noob intuition tells me that it might be related to deep and shallow copies. If z_shallow = x.copy(deep=False) then changes to z_shallow also changes x. While z_deep = x.copy(deep=True) does not modify the original x. However, still not 100% sure how the .iloc is related to deep and shallow copies. Anybody?

Comment: Simple assignment, `x = <something>` **never copies** and simply says "the name `x` now refers to <some-object>". Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: `y = x.iloc[:,:]` assigns a *view* of `x` to `y`, not a copy at all. So when you mutate `y`, you will see this effect on `x`. However, doing `y = 123` is **not a mutation**, it simply assigns `y` to another object.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Thus the problem came from the fact that initially y was a view on x.iloc and then we did a mutation (versus a different new assignment)?

Comment: Read this link: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html for how assignment works in Python.

Comment: Note, slicing generally returns *copies* for built-in python objects, e.g. with `list` objects. However, `numpy` and `pandas` objects will return views if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might answer your question:
[why should I make a copy of a data frame in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673231/why-should-i-make-a-copy-of-a-data-frame-in-pandas)

'In Pandas, indexing a DataFrame returns a reference to the initial DataFrame'