# adding a new column to pandas slow without reset_index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, addition, new-operator

I have `data1` which contains about 20,000 rows:

```
data2=data1[data1.column=="ABC"] #about 100 rows

data1["temp"]=1  #takes no time even though it has 20k rows

data2["temp"]=1 #takes a second!
```

If I call the following, it executes quickly.

```
data2 = data2.reset_index(drop=True);
data2["temp"]=1
```

What am I missing here?  I clearly don't understand what index thing is for in pandas and how to use it.

Comment: You may find this of value: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27673231/8146556