# column names of pandas dataframe change when the columns of another dataframe created from it are changed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

the following piece of code exemplifies my 'problem' or rather wierd behavior of DataFrames:

```
display(df)
df_copy=df
df_copy.columns=['C','D']
display(df)
```

this outputs:

```
    A   B
0   1   1
1   3   3
2   2   6

    C   D
0   1   1
1   3   3
2   2   6
```

Why do the column names change for df, when I only changed them in df_copy?

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673231/why-should-i-make-a-copy-of-a-data-frame-in-pandas

Comment: @TommerArgaman it's an important fundamental concept to use `.copy()`, so a good one to always remember!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.copy()` instead:

```
df_copy = df.copy()
```