# Pandas Dataframe not overwritten in function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, global-variables

So this is my first question here. Please let me know what style guides I failed to use. :)

I have a dataframe and within a function, I create a copy and work with this copy inside the function. Calling the function the first time works fine. The second time gives an error.

```
df_general = pd.read_excel("somedata.xlsx")

def my_func():

    df_within = df_general
    
    # some work with df_within, e.g. adding a column

    return
```

Reason I found: `df_within` is not set back to `df_general` - seems like the statement `df_within = df_general` is not taken up (but is taken up during first time using the function)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: _and within a function, I create a copy_ - no you dont. Use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've quite understood your purpose.

If you are trying to make a copy of it so `df_within` changes wouldn't affect `df_general` you can use panda's [`copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) method as follows:

```
df_general = pd.read_excel("somedata.xlsx")

def my_func():

    df_within = df_general.copy()  # This will create a non-referenced copy by allocating new memory.

    # some work with df_within, e.g. adding a column

    return
```

Also you've stated you have an error the second time, might be a good idea to show us with that error was.

Comment: That is exactly what my mistake was. thanks a lot. Also found a more general guide here for everybody else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673231/why-should-i-make-a-copy-of-a-data-frame-in-pandas

Comment: @Josch I'm glad it helped :)
Make sure you mark it as the correct answer for other people with similar problem to know.