# Replacing existing column in dask map_partitions gives SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm replacing column `id2` in a `dask` dataframe using `map_partitions`. The result is that the values are replaced but with a `pandas` warning.

What is this warning and how to apply the `.loc` suggestion in the example below?

```
pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'dummy2': [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 15, 10, 30, 20, 26],
    'id2': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'balance2': [150, 140, 130, 280, 260, 150, 140, 130, 280, 260]
})

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=3) 

def func2(df):
    df['id2'] = df['balance2'] + 1
    return df

ddf = ddf.map_partitions(func2)

ddf.compute()
```

> C:\Users\xxxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_30076\248155462.py:2:
> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
> value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> df['id2'] = df['balance2'] + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix is to add copy of the dataframe:

```py
def func2(df):
    df = df.copy() # will make a copy of the dataframe
    df['id2'] = df['balance2'] + 1
    return df
```

However, as I understand, copying of the dataframe is not required as the delayed nature of the dask dataframe means that the changes are not propagated back to the dask dataframe partitions.

Update: there is a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27673231/10693596) which explains the reason for `.copy` in `pandas`. In the snippet below applying the function will modify the original pandas dataframe, which might be undesirable:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame

def addcol(df):
    df['a'] = 1
    return df

df = DataFrame()

df1 = addcol(df)
# without .copy, df is also modified, which might be undesirable
```

In the context of `dask` this warning is just that, a warning, so `.copy` is not needed.

```py
from dask.dataframe import from_pandas
ddf = from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)
ddf1 = ddf.map_partitions(addcol)
# will show warning, but original ddf is not modified
```

Comment: What do you achieve by copying the dataframe?

Comment: If you were working with pandas dataframe, then running the original `func2` would modify the dataframe that is passed to `func2` (i.e. both the input dataframe and output dataframe would be modified).

Comment: This worked, however I'm still confused when should I copy the dataframe and when not.

Comment: This expands on it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27673231/10693596

Comment: Ok, so creating a new reference with copy will remove the warning, I get that, but you also said that "copy is not required"?

Comment: Kindly check the updated answer.