# Is copy() still needed for extracting a subset of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the codebase I'm working in, I see the following

```
df1 = some pandas dataframe (one of the columns is quantity)
df1_subset = df1[df1.quantity == input_quantity].copy()
```

I am wondering why the `.copy()` is needed here? Doesn't `df1_subset = df1[df1.quantity == input_quantity]` make `df1_subset` a copy and not a reference?

I saw in [why should I make a copy of a data frame in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673231/why-should-i-make-a-copy-of-a-data-frame-in-pandas) that a reference would be returned, but I think this is outdated?

Comment: This is a safety to avoid a `SettingwithCopyWarning`, using `df1.loc[df1.quantity == input_quantity]` should prevent the need for a copy (provided prior slicing was done properly). See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) for further details on the warning.

Comment: *Doesn't df[...] make a copy* No it's not guaranteed, and in fact it will try to give a view back if it can. Even with `.loc`, the need for copy won't go away to suppress the warning. If you will do modifications to the subset, and you're not having memory concerns (which is rare), you should always chain a copy at the end

Comment: Just try. Do without copy and modify some data on original dataframe, and check if it is modified also in the subset. Note: it may be more memory efficient not to do a copy, but just having the indices (think on wide df with a lot of columns). Possibly Pandas want the freedom to choose the method