# How do you copy a dataframe in polars?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

In polars, what is the way to make a copy of a dataframe?  In pandas it would be:

```
df_copy = df.copy()
```

But what is the syntax for polars?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be [`clone`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.clone.html#polars.DataFrame.clone) :

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "b": [0.5, 4, 10, 13],
        "c": [True, True, False, True],
    }
)

df_copy = df.clone() #cheap deepcopy/clone
```

Output :
​

```
print(df_copy)
​
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c     │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ f64  ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0.5  ┆ true  │
│ 2   ┆ 4.0  ┆ true  │
│ 3   ┆ 10.0 ┆ false │
│ 4   ┆ 13.0 ┆ true  │
└─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

*TLDR.* There is [`pl.DataFrame.clone`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.clone.html). However, you very likely don't actually need to copy your DataFrame.

I suppose some people clicking on this question, [coming from pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27673231/why-should-i-make-a-copy-of-a-data-frame-in-pandas), think that common DataFrame operations are in-place and see the necessity of cloning. However, [*very few*](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/search.html?q=in_place)  operations are actually in-place, none of them are super common, and all of them either highlight this in their name or require an explicit `in_place` parameter to be set.

Still, this doesn't mean that polars is copying data for every operation, which would be super inefficient. It just organises a hierarchy of pointers with pointers to chunked arrays in the apache arrow memory model at the bottom
layer. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78048681/add-a-new-column-into-an-existing-polars-dataframe/78048898#78048898) for more information.